# count clicks on picturebox,count clicks on the form and then count the rate winformapp c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a picture box and a form. I want to count the clicks on these and then to count the ratio of all clicks.

I tried this code for clicks on picturebox

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hitcounter++;
    label3.Text = hitcounter.ToString();
}
```

Then I want to count the clicks on the form and I tried this code

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseCounter++;
}
```

`mouseCounter`, `hitcounter`, and `accuracy` are global variables.

Finally I want to count the rate of hits in picturebox from all clicks. For this I make this

```
public string Accuracy(int mousecounter,int hitcounter)
{
    accuracy = (double)(((double)hitcounter / (double)(mouseCounter + hitcounter + 0.000000001)) * 100);
    return label6.Text = "Accuracy: " + Math.Round(accuracy, 1).ToString() + "%";
}
```

But the strange thing is, when I put the method `Accuracy` into `pictureBox1_Click` when I start the programm in the `label6` doesn't print the correct value, because it ignores the clicks in form and changes the ratio only if first hit the picturebox(for example if I hit first at picturebox I have 100% accuracy but if then click form stay 100% rather than 50%. If the third hit is in picture print the correct value).
In addition if I put only in `Form1_MouseClick` the method `Accuracy` I have the opposite problem .

I try to put at the same time the method `Accuracy` in `pictureBox1_Click` and `Form1_MouseClick` and print the correct value in every click!!

Can someone modify it, or to show me a different solution?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] including the methods that **call** `Accuracy`.

Comment: IMO this boils down to just one misunderstanding. If nothing ever calls `Accuracy`, then there is no label update. And clicks on picturebox are not transparent to the container form. So I'd suggest call `Accuracy()` from both event handlers.

Comment: The label needs to be updated by clicks on *both*.  Another probable bug is that quickly clicking is going to produce a DoubleClick instead of Click.  And it is questionable whether you actually want Click when you perhaps meant to detect MouseDown, Click is only generated when the mouse did not move too much between button down and back up.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help!